# Confirmation on browsers back button

Tags: javascript, ajax

I need to control over back button. I checked similar posts it wont work as i expect.

I need to show custom confirmation message on back button clicked. If uses clicks 'Cancel', then they should stay on the same page.

Can anyone has ready sample code?

Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Since the back button is part of the browser's functionality, not the web page's, the best you can do is handle the [beforeunload](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla_event_reference/beforeunload) event.  This lets you provide a custom cancel message before the user leaves the page for any reason.  Some intelligence about how you set up the handler and adding additional handlers to remove the beforeunload handler before taking links, etc. that should legitimately take the user to a different page can approximate the behavior you are looking for.  See the example on the referenced documentation:

```
window.addEventListener("beforeunload", function( event ) {
  event.returnValue = "a non-empty string";
}, false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the

> onbeforeunload

event instead. It'll triggered before user leaves the page.

Code example:

```
window.addEventListener('beforeunload',function(e){
    !confirm('Do you want to leave?') && e.preventDefault();
},false);
```

Comment: It also works on page reload, and i need it to be call on only Back button. Also it is not working on google crome.